# datatable filter with two conditions

Tags: c#, filter, datatable

I am working with a large datatable. And I need to do some filter to calculate the sum value for certain rows. For the following code, it filters the same IDfile and calculate the sum. My question is if I want to add an other condition combined with IDfile

```
for (int i = 0; i < LoadIDcount; i++)
{
    string IDnow = LoadID[i, 0];

    for (int j = 0; j < 8760; j++)
    {
        string colPnow = SP_dt.Columns[j * 2 + 4].ColumnName.ToString();
        double ColP_sum = (double)SP_dt.Compute(String.Format("Sum([{0}])", colPnow), String.Format("Load_ID = '{0}'", IDnow));
        string colQnow = SP_dt.Columns[j * 2 + 5].ColumnName.ToString();
        double ColQ_sum = (double)SP_dt.Compute(String.Format("Sum([{0}])", colQnow), String.Format("Load_ID = '{0}'", IDnow));


        LoadP_dt.Rows[i][j + 2] = ColP_sum;
        LoadQ_dt.Rows[i][j + 2] = ColQ_sum;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}    {1}", i, j);
    }

}
```

The datatable is like:

```
SP_ID   Load_ID              CUSTOMER_TYPE  Phase   1/1/2015 0:00   
1234567 11111111111          DOM            ABC     3.8928  
2345678 2222222222           DOM            ABC     1.9608  
3456788 33333333             IND            ABC     3.742   
23242   4444444444           IND            ABC     6.9856  
23890583    55555555555      IND            ABC     1.0628
```

I want to add two conditions to the compute to filter both ID and customer type

Comment: Any input samples and expected output?

Comment: Normally, we filter the case when we query, before it becomes data table, using SQL statement. But if that has become a `DataTable`, then maybe `LINQ` query may help. Is `SP_dt` your full data table, containing Column with names: `SP_ID, Load_ID, CUSTOMER_TYPE, Phase`, etc..? And you only want to filter some entries among them, don't you? Consider using `Where` clause.

Comment: Also, seems like you have so many columns: `SP_dt.Columns[j * 2 + 4]` where `j < 8760`?

Comment: yes, a of column. SP_dt is my full table with all the information

Comment: DataTable has a Filter Property do a google search for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add your second condition to the filter. Like this:

```
double ColP_sum = (double)SP_dt.Compute(String.Format("Sum([{0}])", colPnow), String.Format("Load_ID = '{0}' AND Phase = '{1}'", IDnow, 'ABC'));
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx?PHPSESSID=517b5f01557c3ebb58cd543034c3ee29) is the documentation for the Compute method.